# Determine Needed Assemblies When Compiling C# Project

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I am writing a metadata extractor for C# projects. I'm not using MSBuildWorkspace, instead using CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText() and CSharpCompilation.Create().

Checking the diagnostics from the compilation I noticed that I was missing a number of assembly references:

```
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0" ).Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "System.Runtime" ).Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( typeof( object ).Assembly.Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "System.IO.FileSystem" ).Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "System.Runtime.Extensions" ).Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "System.Collections" ).Location ) );
_references.Add( MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Assembly.Load( "System.Private.Uri" ).Location ) );
```

where `_references` is a collection I use in the compilation:

```
compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create( ProjectDocument.AssemblyName )
    .AddReferences( _references.ToArray() )
    .AddSyntaxTrees( trees );
```

and `trees` are the syntax trees I'm compiling.

My question is this: is there a way to determine, from the syntax trees or the .csproj file, exactly what references are needed? I do this for nuget packages added to the project file by parsing the various `<ProjectReference>` nodes. But I'm not sure how to do that for the other references.

Comment: Is it feasible to run a NuGet restore on your project? If it is then it sounds like the `project.assets.json` file may have what you need

Comment: LOL! Thanx, @rbennett485; I should've thought of that myself as I parse that file for other reasons. If you offer your idea as an answer I'd be pleased to accept it as such.

Comment: @rbennett485 may I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404294/resolving-assembly-references-in-roslyn? It's a related question that I'm hoping you may have some insights on.

Comment:  not sure about your other question I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run a NuGet restore then the `project.assets.json` file should have all the information you need